.Net Project Graph SDK Token is expiring when deployed to Azure App Service
I'm struggling a bit with .Net development and getting stuck on my webapp after deploying it into Azure App service.
Basically the access token seems to be expiring after 1h and not refreshing and throwing me the error:
ODataError: Lifetime validation failed, the token is expired.
Currently I have a class called Invite.cshtml.cs that looks like this:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Azure.Identity;

namespace Test_Web_App.Pages
{
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")]
    public class InviteModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
        private static ClientSecretCredential? _clientSecretCredential;
        private static GraphServiceClient? _appClient;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public InviteModel(  ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IConfiguration configuration, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, HttpClient httpClient, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient; ;
            _httpClient = httpClient; ;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

What I've noticed is that this call is not called from My Azure WebApp (but does run when I ran the app locally on my machine) which I assume is why the token never refreshes when I run my app:
public InviteModel(  ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IConfiguration configuration, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, HttpClient httpClient, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient; ;
            _httpClient = httpClient; ;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

The code blows up instantly on my OnPostAsync method as soon as it tries to load the graphServiceClient:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
        var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.GetAsync(); ;

I honestly don't know what I'm missing in here so any help or guidance you can give me would be very appreciated.
Thank you very much in Advance!
As an extra not sure if this helps but currently what I have on my Program.cs is the following:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp( options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        options.SaveTokens = true; // Ensure tokens are saved
    })
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches().AddMicrosoftGraph();
//Named HttpClient with IHttpClientFactory
builder.Services.AddTransient<GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("GraphAPI",
        client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(
            builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph")["BaseUrl"] ??
                string.Empty))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<GraphAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("GraphAPI"));
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); // Add this line to register IHttpContextAccessor
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();


I found that you have 2 .AddMicrosoftGraph in your Program.cs, I think you might delete the one behind AddInMemoryTokenCaches(). By the way, when the web app is hosting in the cloud service, AddDistributedTokenCaches might be a better option but it would bring extra cost which is not necessary if the application is just for test purpose. But I think this will solve your issue.

However I recommend you to try to remove options.SaveTokens = true; and make sure the session affinity is enabled in Azure web app and have a test again to see whether the  issue still exist. https://i.sstatic.net/xPN0vgiI.png

@TinyWang you have no idea how many times i looked into the Program.cs to check the builder and never noticed I had 2 .AddMicrosoftGraph. If I understand well the AddDistributedTokenCaches  can use for example of a Redis cache to be more reliable in persisting the tokens. That could be a good idea for the future to suggest on my team, since for now just need to do a demo for testing this might be enough as is :)
I checked and confirm I do have session affinity enabled on the Azure web app, just removed the options.SaveTokens = true; so hopping for the best. Will update if it works

Thanks a lot for your confirmation : ) your codes looks good and I never had a test in Azure in similar scenario, so that I didn't face your issue before. I'm also concerned about the test result. Thank you again for your updating in advance!

@TinyWang just tried but sadly still didn't work, still getting the token expiry failure. I have no idea why this happens since from what I understood the token should be refreshed by the SDK automatically but it's not happening. Quite weird, but then again it's the first time I'm using this so not sure

yes, the token should be refreshed automatically by SDK, and since the issue doesn't occur when test locally, your codes should be correct. Maybe you can try AddSessionTokenCaches to see whether it's helpful or not.

In a desperation attempt I asked ChatGPT and got suggested to add:
options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>{  var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>();             await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { "user.readwrite.all" });         };
The explanation I got was the OnTokenValidated ensures token refresh, and that ITokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync would get a new token in case of expiry. I'll try this and your suggestion and see if I can fix it :)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

In case someone is in need in the future the problem was with with the azure Web App.
I had App Service authentication enabled. I found it by chance on this github bug where a dev mentioned about "Easy auth":
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/2880
Didn't find this documented anywhere so leaving here for reference.
